# Java Simple Date formatter displaying wrong value

Tags: java, date

Having issue displaying nano seconds using SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSSSSS");     
Date dt = sdf.parse("03.08.2020 05:35:19:7600000"); 
System.out.println("Date  :" + sdf.format(dt) );
```

Output is: `Date  :03.08.2020 07:41:59:0000000.`

Can you please help make the output show nano seconds as: `7600000`? Thanks!

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't support nanoseconds, only milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you switch from the outdated and error-prone legacy date-time API to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSSSSS");
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("03.08.2020 05:35:19:7600000", format);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-03T05:35:19.760
```

Comment: Thank you! Can we store LocalDateTime  in the database as Date object ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Check [this](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html) for an example. You can also convert `LocalDateTime` into `OffsetDateTime` which you can save directly into database e.g. `OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` converts `LocalDateTime` into `OffsetDateTime` by applying the `ZoneOffset` of `UTC`.

Comment: So can i still define my POJO as Date deliveryDate; or OffsetDateTime deliveryDate; ? Database has column defined as date or I can change it to timestamp or time etc. Please suggest.

Comment: The link which I posted in the comment also gives you information about column type. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following and then parse the required date :

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
```

Comment: How does setting a TimeZone help to display the nanoseconds? I tried this, I get  `Date  :03.08.2020 07:41:59:0000000` (You also missed an end parenthesis)